# When was the earliest time that the term "snake case" was used?

Tags: terminology, history, variables

Many people use the term [Snake Case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) to describe variables or other symbols `with_the_form_of_underscores`.

In the past week, I've launched several broad searches. I can't find anything about the origin of this term that is more detailed than what Wikipedia says (above)

When did the earliest record of this term enter into use?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it fails to have done sufficient prior research, or presented it as described on [meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5634/).

Comment: @MichaelT, I revised the body to reflect the work I had done at the time. My searched had really turned up nothing of more substance than Wikipedia, an honestly I feel my edit now only crufts-up an otherwise clean question. This question is quite old, and did quite well, so I hope you can manage a pardon that I no longer have my browser history to link inline for reference.

Comment: I have re-read the FAQ to made the question more answer-able, in addition to more clearly stating the research that I performed.  I cannot do more research without copying the original research of those that answered the question.  I propose this meets the guidelines

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A person named Jack Dahlgren claims [on Quora](http://www.quora.com/Programming-Languages/What-is-the-history-of-the-term-snake-case-snake_case?share=1) he invented the term in 2002 when he worked at Intel.

Here's what he posted at above link:

> I believe that I am the one who coined this term back in 2002 when I
>   was at Intel and we were evaluating Sharepoint Team Services. Based on
>   the unfortunate tendency of Sharepoint to escape spaces in names with
>   [underscore] characters (among other things) I recommended a policy of
>   using underscores to replace all spaces so that URLs would be slightly
>   shorter and much more readable.
>
> Given the existing "camelCase" name with humps in the middle, I called
>   it "snake_case" or if there were two flat spots, I jokingly called it
>   "road_kill_case". Considering the size of Intel and my interactions
>   with Microsoft product team, it is possible that this is the origin,
>   but it is such a simple phase that I think it could have been invented
>   independently elsewhere too.

Answer (score 11):

The earliest use I found in Usenet is in a post by Gavin Kistner to [comp.lang.ruby on 23rd February 2004](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.ruby/ra5WDzNGwGU/oe_mnvRVclUJ):

> While writing my ValidForm library (http://phrogz.net/RubyLibs/) I
> realized that I was mixing camelCase [which I love] with
> whatever_you_call_this_case [which I don't, but I see that Ruby uses a
> lot of]. (BTW...what *do* you call that naming style? snake_case? That's
> what I'll call it until someone corrects me.)

Ruby still uses this term today, for example in [The Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#naming):

> - Use `snake_case` for symbols, methods and variables.
> - Use `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for other constants.

Comment: I always search google groups to find the origin of phrases. That's exactly that I did. And after that I started searching bing/google with "snake case" 2003, "snake case" 2002, etc.

Comment: +1 for putting the image of a snake screaming "I AM ALWAYS 4" at me, in my head.